# How to import local package to docker environment

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I try to run a Go API server in a Docker environment, but it fails to run with an error.

```
・client: react/axios
・api: golang/gin
・web-server: nginx
・db: mysql
・container: docker
・ci-tool: travis
・deploy: aws elastic beanstalk
```

```
article
  ├ client
  ├ api
  │  ├ main.go
  │  ├ contoroller
  │  │    └ contoroller.go
  │  └ Dockerfile
  ├ nginx
  └ docker-compose.yml
```

Here is Dockefile for api

```
//article/api/Dockefile

FROM golang:latest
WORKDIR '/app'
RUN go get github.com/gin-contrib/cors
RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
RUN go get github.com/google/uuid
RUN go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
RUN go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3
RUN go get github.com/joho/godotenv
COPY . .
CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

Here is docker-compose.yml

```
//docker-compose.yml
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_HOST
```

I expect docker-compose up successes, but I get a failure.

```
api_1     | main.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller" in any of:
api_1     |     /usr/local/go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller (from $GOROOT)
api_1     |     /go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker build fails with local go package import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875561/docker-build-fails-with-local-go-package-import)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using go moduls?

Its very popular to use multi stage build docker with Golang.

This will create a very small image.

```
FROM golang:1.12.9-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY ./ ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build \
-installsuffix 'static' \
-o /myapp .

FROM scratch AS final
COPY --from=builder /myapp /myapp

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/myapp"]
```

Notice that you can't run bash on a running container.
When using web service you need to add `ca-certificates`